# Concurrent Java Programming

Tags: java

Im trying to move cars through a junction using semaphores to avoid deadlock. The following code is what I have to make the car move from one space to another.

```
     // Move up to junction
     SlotSem[6].P(); // Wait for section 6 to be free 
     junctionSlots[6] = junctionSlots[8]; // move into next slot
     junctionSlots[8] = "[...]"; // clear slot you vacated
     SlotSem[8].V(); 
     theCarActivity.addMovedTo(6);
```

I was wondering what would be the best way to have random cases for the car to go left, right or straight ahead.

[image]

Comment: So your question is really about being able to create a random number in the range `1` to `3` (inclusive)?

Comment: Ive tried using a switch statement, however when i create the case for each direction my semaphore array is no longer recognised

Comment: Then it's time you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Also please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).